# add output of custom build step to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How do I add the output of a custom build step in visual studio to the c++ project itself?

For example, I have a parser that, as part of the build process, reads in some files, creates .hpp and .cpp in the custom build steps. These output .hpp and .cpp files then need to be added to the project and be built during the same build process.

Is there a way to do all these in a single build in Visual Studio?

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the documentation: [Understanding Custom Build Steps and Build Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/understanding-custom-build-steps-and-build-events?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

You can use build events to specify commands that run before the build starts, before the link process, or after the build finishes.

[Specifying Build Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/specifying-build-events?view=vs-2019) at Microsoft Docs